# Balance imbalanced data-set containing case weights with SMOTE

Tags: r, classification, r-caret

I have been working on a survey of 10K customers who have been segmented into several customer segments. Now due to the nature of the respondents who actually completed the survey the researcher who did the qualitative work applied case weights (also known as probability weights) and supplied the data to me with all customers with one of 8 class labels. So we have a multi-class problem which of course is highly imbalanced.

One approach I have taken is to decompose these classes into a pairwise model which all contribute to a final vote. Now my question is two fold:

1. I am using the wonderful package SMOTE to balance each model to address the class imbalance problem. However, as each customer record has a related case weight SMOTE is treating each customer equally. After applying SMOTE the classes now appear to be equal but if you consider the respective case weights it actually isn't.
2. My second question is relating to my strategy. Should I need not worry about my case weights and just build my classification model on the raw unweighted data even though it doesn't represent the total customer base that I want to classify into each segment.

I have been using the R caret package to build these multiple binary classifiers.

Regards

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the weighting scheme utilized